# How do I uncurl after a partial curl animation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, animation

I am doing a partial page curl in this way:

```
- (IBAction)settings:(id)sender {

    Settings *go = [[[Settings alloc] initWithNibName:@"Settings" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    go.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
    [self presentModalViewController:go animated:YES];
}
```

How do I uncurl this animation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just dismiss the modal view controller as you always do. iOS will take care of the transition as you have already specified the *modalTransitionStyle*.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
-(IBAction)backClicked{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try to tap on left top corner with part of curl page to automatically dismiss view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Information for > ios 6.0: 
*dismissModalViewControllerAnimated* is deprecated now.

The new method it´s without "modal", looks like that:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```