# how to remove partial curl back feature

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am using partial curl as model transition style but after it presents, it will take me to previous view controller if I touch any near top of the screen. 
Here is the code I am using to present

```
let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTabBarViewController") as! UITabBarController
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .partialCurl
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Thank You! in advance

Comment: Just dismiss the modal view controller as you always do. iOS will take care of the transition as you have already specified the modalTransitionStyle.[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239265/how-do-i-uncurl-after-a-partial-curl-animation

Comment: no its not working i tried it and also remove gesture recogniser but still facing the same issue.